# Align the Links in my Responsive Navbar with Dropdown Menu, so that it lines up with the website content

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive

I used the code I found at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp), and I styled it to my taste in order to create my websites top navigation menu:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
/* Add a background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #0066ff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #4d94ff;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #b3d1ff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #99c2ff;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #cce0ff;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* */
.content {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e3;
  color: #4a536e;
}

.content .block {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.content .block p {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

/* When the screen is less than 1000 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"> 
    <a href="../" class="active" title="Homepage"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="/members/home.php" title="Member's Homepage"><i class="fa-solid fa-door-open"></i> Member's Homepage</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" title="Sections"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i> Sections <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/members/music/" title="Enjoy Our Music Section"><i class="fa-solid fa-music"></i> Music Section</a>
          <a href="/members/polls/" title="Vote in A Poll"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i> Polls Section</a>
    </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" title="Help"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i> Help <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/members/tickets/" title="Create a Ticket For An Issue"><i class="fas fa-ticket"></i> Ticket System</a>
        <a href="contact/" title="Send A Message to Site Administration"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact Form</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a href="profile.php" title="Profile Page"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Profile</a>
    <a href="logout.php" title="Bye Bye"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>  
    </div>
         
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
    </script> 
     
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Member's Page</h2>
      <h2>WELCOME TO THE MEMBERS ONLY SECTION!</h2>
    </div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

However I can't figure out how to align the links in the navigation menu with the site content. The links in the navigation menu always goes to the edge of the screen (on the left side). I want to get the links from the left side lined up with the left side of the text in the site content (but not go past the right most part of the site content). I would also like to place the website's title in the navigation menu, on the left side before the links, but keeping it aligned with the rest of the site's content.

Is there an easy fix for this styling issue?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: For clarification: Is your expected design that the website title shall appear above the "Member's Page" and that "Member's Page" shall stay where it currently is? And then right of the website title the currently shown "Home" and so on. Also, "but not go past the right most part of the site content": How do you define the right most part and what do you want to have if the header gets longer (e.g. because of the website title)?

Comment: Yes, I want the Website Title to appear above the "Member's Page" text in the body, and have the "Member's Page" text stay where it is, then to the right of the Website Title, the "Home" link, "Member's Homepage" link, etc, etc. The right most part of the site content would be defined as the right side or end of the dividing line that is under the "Member's Page" & "WELCOME TO THE MEMBERS ONLY SECTION!" text. If the header gets too long I would like the text of the links or Website title to appear on top of each other; for example if the website title is two words, then 1st word above 2nd word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired changes, we need to modify both html and css. For the html part, I added another div inside of 'topnav', gave it a class 'nav-links' and put all the contents of 'topnav' to inside it. In the css, remove the 'max-width and margin' from topnav and add this styles to 'nav-links'. You can also make the default padding and margin for the body zero (Browsers add a default margin and padding due to which your navbar won't extend completely up to end).

Here's the css changes:

```
* {
/* Removed the default margin and padding values */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

.topnav {
background-color: #0066ff;
overflow: hidden;
/* removed the max-width & margin values */}

.nav-links {
/* Added both max-width & margin values */
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

And the html changes:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"><div class="nav-links"><a href="../" class="active" title="Homepage"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a><a href="/members/home.php" title="Member's Homepage"><i class="fa-solid fa-door-open"></i>Member's Homepage</a><div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" title="Sections"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>Sections<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="/members/music/" title="Enjoy Our Music Section"><i class="fa-solid fa-music"></i>Music Section</a><a href="/members/polls/" title="Vote in A Poll"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i>Polls Section</a></div></div><div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" title="Help"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i>Help<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button><div class="dropdown-content"><a href="/members/tickets/" title="Create a Ticket For An Issue"><i class="fas fa-ticket"></i>Ticket System</a><a href="contact/" title="Send A Message to Site Administration"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contact Form</a></div></div><a href="profile.php" title="Profile Page"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Profile</a><a href="logout.php" title="Bye Bye"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The new .nav-links div class html changes, and css styling changes achieved the desired effect. I did have to leave in the margin: 0 auto; in the .content css part, otherwise the page's content would go to the left side edge of the window rather than being aligned with the menu bar's links. Issue resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The div having class 'content' has a fixed width of 1000px, just remove that in css and you are done!

```
.content {
    /*removed the width of 1000px */
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* added padding for making it better */
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this had the opposite effect that I was trying to achieve. Your solution made the content under the top navigation menu go to the left most edge of the screen. I wanted the top navigation bar links to go to the indented content in the site. However you solution has given me the information I needed to do just that. I'll post an answer later today once I've achieved my goal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).